# .htaccess rule to insert a directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, directory

Could someone please help me write this htaccess rule? I have found nothing relevant on the web :( Here is the flow I'd like:

**1) someone opens the url site.com/12345 (any 5 numbers)**

**2) he must be redirected to site.com/de/12345**

I use Wordpress and I already have these 2 redirects live:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# force ssl
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Danny

Answer (score 0):

For permenate redirects try this:

```
redirect 301 /^[0-9]{5}$ http://www.yoursite.com/de/$1
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy! But it doesn't really work. I don't see any effect at all :(